# Template member function containing decltype(lambda) default template parameter has divergent behaviour on different compilers

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, compiler-errors, c++20

The code below compiles fine with Clang trunk and does not compile with GCC trunk at the time of posting.
An interesting phenomenon of note is the fact that the GCC error message has no diagnostics besides the fact that template argument deduction failed.

```cpp
template<typename>
struct foo {
    template<typename = decltype([]{})>
    void bar() {}
};

int main() {
    [[maybe_unused]] auto v = foo<void>();

    v.bar<int>();            // OK
    v.bar<decltype([]{})>(); // OK

    // compiles if these two lines are commented out:

    v.bar<>();               // deduction failure
    v.bar();                 // deduction failure
}
```

godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/hrqcefvb8

Compiler output:

```cpp
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:15:12: error: no matching function for call to 'foo<void>::bar<>()'
   15 |     v.bar<>();               // deduction failure
      |     ~~~~~~~^~
<source>:4:10: note: candidate: 'template<class> void foo< <template-parameter-1-1> >::bar() [with <template-parameter-1-1> = void]'
    4 |     void bar() {}
      |          ^~~
<source>:4:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:16:10: error: no matching function for call to 'foo<void>::bar()'
   16 |     v.bar();                 // deduction failure
      |     ~~~~~^~
<source>:4:10: note: candidate: 'template<class> void foo< <template-parameter-1-1> >::bar() [with <template-parameter-1-1> = void]'
    4 |     void bar() {}
      |          ^~~
<source>:4:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Compiler returned: 1
```

But interestingly enough, the code below compiles on both compilers:

```cpp
template<typename = decltype([]{})>
void foo() {}

int main() {
    foo<>();
    foo();
}
```

godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/dbd7GTrqj

My question is why the first snippet does not compile on GCC if it is not a bug.
While it is not the focus of this question, it would be nice to have the empty substitution failure message produced by GCC explained.

My rationalisation as to how the decltype(<stateless lambda expression>) default parameter might not be accepted as a default parameter is a combination of `[defns.signature.templ]` including `parameter-type-list` and "signature of the `template-head`" combined with Note 4 in `[temp.fct]` which clarifies that lambda types cannot appear in any "linked" symbols. This, however, is likely not the answer to why GCC does not compile as `[defns.signature.template.head]` clearly excludes default arguments from the signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a confirmed bug in gcc.

There is a meta-bugreport, [Bug 107430 (c++-lambda-decltype) - [meta-bug] lambda in decltype](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=107430), which has this description:

> I noticed there are many issues with lambda inside a `decltype` issues. Especially dealing with template alias.

It has a large collection of lambda/`decltype` related bugs.

I opened a new one:
[Bug 110604 - template argument deduction failed with decltype(lambda)](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=110604) containing your exact code and that bug report was linked as a duplicate of this **confirmed** bug:
[Bug 93595 - [c++20] function call, substitution failure of template paramter with a lambda default in template context](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=93595)

Comment: While that bug report does appear to be similar, both the title and the people in the comments point out that the bug being reported is about out of line member function definitions. Moreover, the bug being reported appears to be one about parsing while the error I am getting is about deduction failures with default parameters.

Comment: @NitoriKawashiro I opened a new bugreport. If it's a duplicate or not, we'll probably see shortly.

Comment: I have updated the first example to add clarification about the specifics of the issue. Also, thanks for reporting this to the GCC bug tracker.